# How to do multiple search in react instanst search library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

I want to do multiple search using react instant search library at the same time.

For example suppose if i want to search in search bar for mobile category like Samsung and apple in one search some thing like "Samsung, Apple" or different search for filtering multiple category than i should get the all result related to Samsung and Apple mobile as result is this possible in react instant search library if yes than how?